# How create border around visible image in ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

It is possible to create contour around or shadow under VISIBLE pixels in ImageView.

In case this image in ImageView (outside from green figure is transparent):

[image]

I need next pic with border:

[image]

Please any code or references.

Comment: it will be easy if you post your code

Comment: try https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

Comment: @akash yadav, thank you, but I not need create circular image. I need create border around any visible figure inside imageview. This is not circle or square, it is may by any figure, any picture. It may be with holes inside.

Comment: it will be hard....tell answer if you come to know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Dunno you just want to add a color as stroke to the background then you can do like this
If you are using color then you can create an xml file in  the drawable in the res of your project 
and create a drawable like this

```
Image.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#007cea" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />

    <solid android:color="#007cea" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

And to your imageview you can call the xml file as

```
 android:background="@drawable/login_button"
```

In the xml file you specify like this

```
 <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#007cea" />
```

the  android:color="#007cea" defines which color you want to give as border

Comment: This code implement around ImageView (or around any sqare-View). But I need border around visible (not transparent) path of the Image (Drawable, Bitmap) in the ImageView. Visible path may be absolutely any, not square or circle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find exactly what you want.
If it was drawable possibly you could use [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) option.

But it won't work with Imageview.